# how to restore azure app service published static content with no backup or snapshot is configured

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, backup

I have deleted the published static content folder from the app service accidentally. there is no backup or snapshot recovery setting configured. Can I recover my static data back by any means?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure - redeploy from source control. You are using source control.....right?

Comment: to @mason 's point - you published **from** somewhere, right?

Comment: I have tried, and it is indeed possible to recover deleted files, but it takes a long time, about 5 to 10 minutes (mainly depending on the size of the published file).

Comment: Hi @JasonPan, I don't have a premium service plan right now, if I take a plan now, it will be for future reference right? I want to restore the images folder which I accidentally deleted on 3rd March

Comment: You temporarily upgrade the services plan, and after you find the required files, lower the service plan back. This should be the only way to find the file, without source code control.

Comment: If your web app has a lot of users, please create slot and copy all file from main site, and set traffic. Because, when you restore app, it will doesn’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Restore an app from a snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-restore-snapshots#restore-an-app-from-a-snapshot)

> Snapshots automatically create periodic restore points of your app when hosted in a Premium App Service plan.

[image]

**You need upgrade your services plan first.**

From the screenshoot, we can find that our webapp is automatically backed up every hour. Going back to the previous version where you deleted the file should solve your problem.