# Revert back changes in azure webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have one small application running in azure app service which has enabled devops pipeline deployment, by mistake we have done the commit in master branch so pipeline triggered and deployed a new code.

Problem is there is one master DB file which should not be replaced but its replaced and we lost the data, is there any way to revert back the changes in app service? we dont have any backups enabled for app service and in repo its old db file

Please help me if any ideas.

Comment: if you're using sql database, it has auto backups

Comment: no we are not using sql database, its a single page application where data sits in DB.mdb file, in git hub its old version file and that got replaced

Comment: If it’s stored in git, it’s not clear why you can’t just retrieve the database file from the previous commit.

Comment: @esqew  Apologies for confusion in git we maintain latest code base but only one file is not latest that is .mdb file all changes we have done from last one year sits in that file(file is on webapp) this file got over written from github(old mdb file here)

Comment: Do you mean your DB.mdb file under wwwroot ?

Comment: You can check my answer, it maybe useful to you. When you get files , you also can change your plan like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore your app from a snapshot, then you can find files you want.

## But first, you need to upgrade your App Service plan to `Premium`.

*For more details, you can refer my answer in below post.*

[how to restore azure app service published static content with no backup or snapshot is configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482504/how-to-restore-azure-app-service-published-static-content-with-no-backup-or-snap/66488826#66488826)

Comment: Why not just vote to close the question as a duplicate instead?

Comment: @esqew I'm not sure if this is what the op wants, I want to follow up, if not, I can update my answer.

Comment: @esqew Voting to close the question of low-scoring users, if you really encounter a special problem and fail to get an answer, it will cause a poor experience for new users.

Comment: All posts are subject to the same quality guidelines and Stack Overflow etiquette, regardless of how much reputation a user has. The site’s mission is better served by maintaining its quality than most anything else.